# Why is the option to start web2py scheduler no longer working in widget?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, web2py

I recently move to the latest version of web2py to try and resolve an issue with the scheduler.

However now the widget will not let me start the scheduler thread.

I have a scheduler.py file in the models folder.

I can start the scheduler by passing passing paramerter `-K app_name` to web2py but this is not ideal.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Widget screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe [this commit](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/commit/b517c898b84769d82127d5ce3df8e09b77816790#diff-e3d5ad780b88ca2841fadbd25ece7475R327) did it. Not sure of the exact reason, though there is some discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/web2py-developers/uJoQeUlCABw/-MCXocwGAgAJ). Feel free to submit a Github issue.